# is it possible to commit and push .git/config file?

Tags: git, svn

Our remote git repository have been migrated from SVN to git but we are unable to see the older logs.
So i have changed the .git/config file to point to svn location and used git svn fetch command after which i am able to see the older logs. I have tried git status but it showing nothing to be committed so is it possible to commit that file so that other users can see the logs?

Comment: No, it's not part of the history. But when you say "migrated", do you really mean that; it doesn't sound like it

Comment: Actually i don't know in the detail but they said that this repo has been migrated from SVN. And there is no commit from the SVN. Is there anyway this config file will available for others who clone this repo?